# How to render a component that is stored under a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a class that is stored as a property inside another class.

Here is the main upper class:

**updatable_number.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SimpleNumber from "./simple_number.jsx"
import SimpleNumberUpdater from "./simple_number_updater.jsx"

export default class UpdatableNumber extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number_value: this.props.value
        };

        this.number = <SimpleNumber value={this.state.number_value}/>;
        this.updater = <SimpleNumberUpdater target={this.number}/>;
        console.log(this.number);
        console.log(this.updater);

        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    }

    render () {
        // note that if I do `this.number` instead of `this.updater`, it works
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.updater}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, when I do this I get the error `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {isMounted, enqueueSetState, enqueueReplaceState, enqueueForceUpdate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

This is odd to me because when I was doing the *exact same thing* with `this.number` it worked just fine, displaying the number correctly.

How can I display the `updater` in the render function?

Here are `simple_number_updater.jsx` and `simple_number.jsx` in case they help:

**simple_number_updater.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SimpleNumberUpdater extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            target: this.props.target
        };

        this.handle_increment = this.handle_increment.bind(this);
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);

    }

    handle_increment () {
        this.target.setState({ value: this.target.state.value + 1});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={ this.handle_increment }>Increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**simple_number.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SimpleNumber extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value
        };

        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <span className="primary">{this.state.value}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what returns `console.log(this.updater)` please, and why at first glance you want to put it in a property?

Comment: I'm not a ReactJS pro' but by this way you just break the ReactJS pattern then it is possible that your component just doesn't pass the factual-test and that why you get the error

Comment: @Webwoman `console.log(this.updater)` gives `{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: ƒ, key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}`, which isn't all that helpful. I just forgot to delete it.

Comment: @Webwoman what is the factual-test?

Comment: @Webwoman I would like to put it into a property so that I can attach the incrementor button to whatever number component I'd like.

Comment: By factual-test, I mean the test of facts, work or doesn't works simply.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to modularize your incrementor button if I understand well, I think you should review your react pattern because you put a lot in the `this` object, you should instead use the state If you want to make a component reusable, just export it and pass the variable you want to reuse as props, as following:

Also note that by exporting and importing your button you can already use it directly in the render as following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SimpleNumber from "./simple_number.jsx"
import SimpleNumberUpdater from "./simple_number_updater.jsx"

export default class UpdatableNumber extends Component {

       state = {  // in recent React version you can remove the  constructor 
                  // and just put your value inside the business_logic part of your component
            number_value: this.props.value
       }



    render () { 
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <SimpleNumber hereAProps={this.state.someState}/>
                    <SimpleNumberUpdater hereAnotherProps={this.state.someState}  />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My advice: 
- review the state
- review the props communication between parent and child
then re-give a shot